# Multisite user roles - capabilities not working

Tags: multisite, user-roles

I have turned my WP to Multisite and when I try to assing different roles to users, the role is assigned correctly - or at least it looks like (if you have user overview), but the capabilites are still as admin's. :(
Any idea how to fix it? Old role on the main site has kept their capabilities without problem. Thanks a lot